# How to get Electron cookies in Angular js?

Tags: angularjs, electron, electron-builder

I am just creating an Electron app and I have created cookies in my main.js (node js). `session.fromPartition('persist:sessionName').cookies`
Using this i can set and get cookies data on node js, I want to manage these cookies on Angular JS.

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the cookies and get back from cookies

```
var session = require('electron').remote.session;
    var ses = session.fromPartition('persist:name');
    var expiration = new Date();
    var hour = expiration.getHours();
    hour = hour + 6;
    expiration.setHours(hour);
    var value = {
        name: "testname"
    };
    ses.cookies.get(value, function(error, cookies) {
        console.log(cookies); // the value saved on the cookie
    });
    ses.cookies.set({
        url: "http://localhost/",
        name: "testname",
        value: "data",
        expirationDate: expiration.getTime()
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```